# log4net info hangs console application if called from a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net

I have a problem where log4net hangs on a info statement. I have a C# multithreaded console application. The main thread creates several working threads that log using log4net, writing to a file and to the console. The logger is a static variable in some base class. At some random point into executing the application the logger will hang on a info statement, but only on some machines. I came across some post about rare cases where on specific system setups the log write buffer will fill and log4net will wait for it to empty, what never happens. Thus the application hangs. In my case the logger writes into the file, but then stops and the message does not reach the console. Pressing ctrl-c on the console actually causes the application to continue normally.

I tried to make the logger a member of my class instead of having it static as suggested here: http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Multi-threaded-ASP-NET-application-not-working-td21782.html

But that just caused my application to hang at the first log statement there was.

This is the call where it hangs:

```
_logger.Info($"Generation: {_ea.CurrentGeneration}/{_maxGenerations}, " +
          $"Time/gen: {timePerGen} ms, Est. time remaining: {Utilities.TimeToString(timeRemainingEst)} " +
          $"Fitness - Max: {_ea.Statistics._maxFitness:F4} Mean: {_ea.Statistics._meanFitness:F4}, " +
          $"Complexity - Max: {_ea.Statistics._maxComplexity:F0} Mean: {_ea.Statistics._meanComplexity:F2} " +
          $"Champ: {_ea.CurrentChampGenome.Complexity:F0} Strategy: {_ea.ComplexityRegulationMode}, " +
          $"Specie size - Max: {_ea.Statistics._maxSpecieSize:D} Min: {_ea.Statistics._minSpecieSize:D}, " +
          $"Generations since last improvement: {_ea.CurrentGeneration - _lastMaxFitnessImprovementGen}"
          );
```

Has anyone encountered similar issues and know how to fix it or a workaround?

Here is the requested log4net config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="ENTM/%property{name}/%property{id}/%property{count}/log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level:  %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <target value="Console.Error" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level:  %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: I recall something similar in a Windows Service project I wrote a few years ago, but I think I simply created methods in my main thread that did all the logging throughout the application and simply called them via my sub components via a message sent to the main thread component. Make sense?

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill try that

Comment: Can you show your configuration? Are you logging to a fileappender?

Comment: I have updated the post with my config. There is a file and a console appender

Comment: I have the exact same issue with a mono thread console Application

Comment: I had this issue and it resolved itself when I restarted my system. It might have been sufficient to restart VS. Don't know, worth trying. Can't reproduce.